# How to use MaxRequestBodySize in ASP.NET Core on IIS with maxAllowedContentLength?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I have an ASP.NET Core web API running on IIS. In an operation, I set `IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature.MaxRequestBodySize` to `262144000`. I have used the IIS Configuration Editor to

- modify `ApplicationHost.config` for my site by setting `system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/maxAllowedContentLength` to `4294967295` [image]
- modify `ApplicationHost.config` for my site by setting `system.webServer/serverRuntime/maxRequestEntityAllowed` to `4294967295` [image]
- modify `Root Web.config` for my site by setting `system.web/httpRuntime/maxRequestLength` to `2147483647` [image]

Those are the values I also see when I choose `Web.config` in the IIS Configuration Editor.

The site is behind another IIS site acting as a reverse proxy. I have made the same changes there.

I am able to upload files larger than the default ~30MB limit, but I consistently get the following warning whenever I set `IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature.MaxRequestBodySize` to a large value:

> Increasing the MaxRequestBodySize conflicts with the max value for IIS limit maxAllowedContentLength. HTTP requests that have a content-length greater than maxAllowedContentLength will still be rejected by IIS. You can disable the limit by either removing or setting the maxAllowedContentLength value to a higher limit.

I have even looked at the ASP.NET source code to verify that the warning only prints if you're trying to set the limit higher than the IIS settings ([[1]](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/214df1c8ef0cce27b04fcc43d7df48b29964dee1/src/Servers/IIS/IIS/src/Core/IISHttpServer.cs#L85-L88), [[2]](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/df712cc4a97d0bc8d573979008a5a2cc381f8117/src/Servers/IIS/IIS/src/Core/IISHttpContext.FeatureCollection.cs#L370-L373)).

What am I doing wrong?

If it's relevant, I am publishing to IIS using Azure Pipelines. My repo does not contain a `web.config`, but for good measure I tried with the following `web.config` without luck:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there are several bugs in ASP.NET Core when setting the limits to values above Int32.MaxValue. Furthermore, the limit must be set in two places. See [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24555) and linked issues. In summary:

- Set the `web.config` value `system.webServer.security.requestFiltering.maxAllowedContentLength` to `Int32.MaxValue`
- In the app startup, set `IISServerOptions.MaxRequestBodySize` to `Int32.MaxValue`

That removes the warning (and of course limits requests to ~2GB).

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the below code in Startup.cs file:

```
services.Configure<FormOptions>(opt =>
{
    opt.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = YOUR_MAX_TOTAL_UPLOAD_SIZE;
});
```

You could configure/modify maxAllowedContentLength property in your local web.config and deploy your app with web.config to your Azure Website.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
   <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
       <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
     </handlers>
     <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
       <environmentVariables />
     </aspNetCore>
   </system.webServer>
 </location>
 <system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="YOUR_BYTES" />
       </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't use form or multipart transfers, so I can't imagine that being relevant. Also it would be weird if a local `web.config` helps, because the increased values should already be in effect on the server. At least that's what the IIS Configuration Editor shows. Also it's not an Azure website, it's an on-prem Windows Server (but deployed to via Azure Pipelines). In any case, I'll try your suggestions and report back.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I updated my question with the `web.config` I tried. I didn't try the `FormOptions` because 1) I don't use forms, and 2) that's in code, and the request is stopped at the IIS level.

Comment: Tried this, doesnt work. Same error message.