# ASP.NET Core Webapplication hosted on IIS 0-byte download of 500mb zip file does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following situation:
I have a ASP.NET Core 3.1 Service hosted on IIS which shall allow a download of a zip-File (500 mb). Nevertheless, the download results in a 0-byte file (http request).

Since I reuse my download implementation all over my application, I can download smaller files such as 5MB Zip Files, Pdfs, csv, etc without any issue, so I can say my download implementation (serverside and clientside) should work as expected.

I tried to research the issue and tried the following links:

- [How to use MaxRequestBodySize in ASP.NET Core on IIS with maxAllowedContentLength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172966/how-to-use-maxrequestbodysize-in-asp-net-core-on-iis-with-maxallowedcontentlengt) by configuring this in the web.config
- [A 0-byte file might be returned when compression is enabled on a server that is running IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/0-byte-file-compression-enabled)

My question is does anybody have an idea how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @TheobaldDu I know that page but I do not know how this page should help me to fix my problem. would you like to explain yourself?

Comment: After modifying the web.config file, try to re-deploy the webapplication or restart the application pool.